# Hapi 17: Perform an action after response has been sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm upgrading a service to hapi 17 and I've come across an issue that I don't know how to port to the new hapi.

My handler method used to look like this (based on generator functions):

```
removeItem(request, reply) {
  function* main() {
    const { id } = params;

    const removedItem = yield this.apiService.removeComment(id);

    reply(removedItem);

    this.activityStream
      .publishActivity('ITEM_DELETE', item)
      .catch(e => this.errorHelper.handleError(e));
  }

  co(main.bind(this))
    .catch(e => reply(this.errorHelper.handleError(e)));
}
```

Here is an attempt to port it to hapi17 which does not work - it throws a 500 although all the actions went well:

```
async removeItem(request, h) {
  try {
  const { id } = params;

  const removedItem = await this.apiService.removeComment(id);

  h.response(removedItem);

  this.activityStream
    .publishActivity('ITEM_DELETE', item)
    .catch(e => this.errorHelper.handleError(e));
    } catch(err) {
        return this.errorHelper.handleError(err)
    }
 }
}
```

Do you know how to fix it in hapi 17, so that the behaviour is the same? I.e. the response is sent to user before the last action has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are not returning a response from your handler. You create a response with `h.response(removedItem)` but never returned. Also your `this.activityStream.publishActivity` looks like a promise then you should wait or handle its resolution before sending a request.

Here is my suggestions to your code,

```
async function removeItem(request, h) {
    try {
        const {id} = request.params;
        const removedItem = await this.apiService.removeComment(id);
        // apparently, this is also looks like a promise, if not, remove the await keyword
        await this.activityStream
            .publishActivity('ITEM_DELETE', item); // <== where is this ITEM coming from?

        // just return your response
        return removedItem;
    } catch (e) {
        // also just return your error or wrap this with a Boom instance
        return this.errorHelper.handleError(e);
    }
}
```

Boom: https://github.com/hapijs/boom

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. I guess what we were doing in the previous version must have been some kind of a hack as it worked with sending the reply and after that performing other actions (this way not blocking the user from getting the response). It looks like this is not possible in the new hapi, so I'll have to move the actions around and send the response once everything completes.